# Do I use the canvas element or just a plain div holder for an Interactive image carousel/slider with hotspots?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, javascript-framework, html5-canvas

I need to make a interactive image gallery (or image slider) where some hotspots need be placed on. It has to be possible to click on those hotspots, to update a sidebar with the corresponding info. Some basic animation must also be possible on a slide or scene of the gallery.

Which setup would be the best solution.
I'm currently thinking about the canvas element, but the lack of specific events for drawn hotspots makes me doubt. [EaselJS](http://easeljs.com/) could be a solution though.

An alternative could be just using a regular javascript image gallery and place some fixed positioned hotspots on it.

This is actually a basic mvc-setup, I have the image gallery, hotspots and the sidebar.
Should I use a javascript mvc library like http://javascriptmvc.com/ or [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)

So my question actually is, what would be the best setup, with performance and some basic animation in mind?

Thanks.

other interesting links I found:

- http://processingjs.org
- http://raphaeljs.com
- ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying large images or expect users to have older browsers or browsers without current GPU acceleration then you should always use standard HTML4 elements to get this done. Using canvas is overkill and will cause you pain later on if you are not overly-experienced with it.

With DOM-based images you already have click events and can even use image maps to do the click-regions. With canvas you need to code your own click detection and map mouse position to a region to check for clicks.

All in all the simplest solution is usually the best one and for performance and ease of dev, canvas is not the way forward in my opinion.

Comment: thanks, project is finished now. I chose indeed to stick with jquery and a simple gallery. Will post the result here when am I allowed :)